# Elliptic curve over Galois Field, Blockchain

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-fields

I am interested in the elliptic curve
$$
y^2 = x^3 + 7
$$
where both $x$ and $y$ are in the finite residue class field $F_p$ with $p=2^{256}-2^{32}-2^9-2^8-2^7 -2^6-2^4 -1$. Those parameters are used in the secp256k1 standard.

There are $N$ tuples $(x,y)$, $N=115'...'337$. I assume this number is computed using the ideas by Schoof? What's the strategy to compute a point (x,y) on this curve such that the cyclic group generated by this point is matching $N$.

Comment: The group order $N$ is a prime and hence any non-zero point is a generator. Just pick any $x$ chances are good that this is the $x$-coordinates of a point. - Having said this, I don't think this question belongs to this forum as it is not about mathematical research.

Comment: The algorithm of Schoof et al. *could* be used,
but is overkill in this case, because the elliptic curve $E : y^2 = x^3 + 7$
has complex multiplication by cube roots of unity.
The prime $p = 2^{256} - 2^{32} - 977$
is $1 \bmod 3$, so the number $N$ of ${\bf F}_p$-points on $E$ is
$p+1-a$ where the "trace" $a$ satisfies $4p-a^2 = 3b^2$ for some
integer $b$.(*)  We can find all six such $a$ using
Cornacchia's algorithm (see e.g. its Wikipedia entry),
and since $N$ is prime we're quickly done as suggested by
**Chris Wuthrich** (e.g. take $x=1$).

Comment: ($*$) *Warning*: the count of $N$ points includes the "point at infinity"
which is the origin of the group law and has $x=y=\infty$.   So it's not quite
the same as the number of solutions of $y^2 = x^3 + 7 \bmod p$.

Comment: Thank you @NoamD.Elkies and Chris Wuthrich. It's not quite clear to me how you get so quickly to 4p - a^2 = 3b^2 for some integer b? I assume there is no quick answer for b? I guess I have dive deeper into the business of Frobenius maps. Chris: Yes, I don't do mathematical research. Given the quality of all your answers here I doubt I could have found a better place. Big thank you from an amateur...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Schoof's point counting algorithm (1985) is generally used for this purpose. See R. Schoof: *Elliptic Curves over Finite Fields and the Computation of Square Roots mod p.* Math. Comp., 44(170):483–494, 1985.

It was the first deterministic polynomial time (in the size of the elliptic curve group, which is a prime here) algorithm for counting points on elliptic curves.

Schoof's algorithm was improved by Elkies and Atkin.

**Disclaimer:** I am not an expert in this area, but the answer is common knowledge if one works/teaches cryptography. The paper G. Musiker: *Schoof's Algorithm for Counting Points on* $E({\mathbb  {F}}_{{q}})$ available online [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~musiker/schoof.pdf) may help as well.

Comment: In fact, I teach in the area :-) I am preparing a course for students of finance/economics on distributed ledger technology and the blockchain. We may briefly touch elliptic curve cryptography. I shall have mercy with them...